# Pick 3D numpy array with 1D array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

Given that there is 2 Numpy Array :
3d_array with shape (100,10,2),
1d_indices with shape (100)

What is the Numpy way/equivalent to do this :

```css
result = []
for i,j in zip(range(len(3d_array)),1d_indices):
    result.append(3d_array[i,j])
```

Which should return result.shape (100,2)

The closest I've come to is by using fancy indexing on Numpy :

```js
result = 3d_array[np.arange(len(3d_array)), 1d_indices]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to you end up with result being of shape (10010,2) with this particular example. What do you want NumPy for ?

Comment: Hi, yup sorry, editted the question now. Hope it clear things up

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet should be equivalent to `3d_array[:, 1d_indices].reshape(-1,2)`, example:

```
a = np.arange(100*10*2).reshape(100,10,2) # 3d array
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100) # 1d indices

def fun(a,b):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in b:
      result.append(a[i,j])
  return np.array(result)

assert (a[:, b].reshape(-1, 2) == fun(a, b)).all()
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. The snippet I attached was wrong and didn't reflected what I am looking for.